# Examples of using seit as a dative preposition

Tags: preposition, dative

I'm trying to find some different examples of seit + dative. The only ones I can seem to find are with 'Jahren' ie - ich wohne seit zwei Jahren in Frankfurt.

I am also seeing this as an example - Seit er krank ist, spielt er nicht mehr Fußball. This example is confusing me as it's not using dative but 'er'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *seit* is a conjunction as well as a preposition ruling the dative.
Examples for usage as a preposition:

*Ich wohne seit zwei Jahren in Frankfurt.*

*Seit seiner Erkrankung spielt er nicht mehr Fußball.*

*Seit meinem vierzigsten Geburtstag fühle ich mich viel weiser.*

*Er hat seit seiner Scheidung keinen Urlaub mehr gemacht.*

Examples for usage as an conjunction:

*Ich wohne in Frankfurt, seit ich aus Leipzig weggezogen bin.*

*Seit er krank ist, spielt er nicht mehr Fußball.*

*Seit ich vierzig geworden bin, fühle ich mich viel weiser.*

*Er hat keinen Urlaub mehr gemacht, seit er geschieden wurde.*

Comment: That's a (subordinating) conjunction, not an adverb.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.